# Как уменьшить вес видео python

Tags: python, видео, сжатие

Нужно уменьшить вес файла.

Данный подход уменьшает размер лишь на 100 КБ:

```
import moviepy.editor as moviepy
clip = moviepy.VideoFileClip("myvideo.avi")
clip.write_videofile("myvideo.mp4")
```

Данный вообще не уменьшает его вес:

```
import os 

os.system('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4')
```

Что можно сделать ещё?

Comment: Очевидно, `-b 800k` исправить на какое-нибудь меньшее значение

Comment: а ты понимаешь от чего зависит вес видеофайла?